# Newbie question: How do I properly factor code in a simple form handler w/ React and Apollo client

Tags: reactjs, forms, apollo-client

**Question**:  regarding React+ApolloClient form handling described below, can anyone tell me the 'right' way to handle this situation or point me to a good tutorial.  The modularization and organizing of code is confusing me, even in this simple case.

**Code Details**:
I have a react App() component with a child functional component, SignUp(props), which renders the signup page and form.  (I am sticking to only react functional components RFC and hooks -no class components- to avoid being overwhelmed)

The SignUp() component manages the form fields in an object `fields` on its state.  The onSubmit event in the SignUp() form calls handleSubmit() which then calls e.preventdefault, and then calls a **non-rfc** function handleSignUp(fields), which I had passed down into Login() on its props.

I was able to successfully get the form data lifted up to parent App().

From there, I hoped to use useMutation() to create a new user on my graphql server.
BUT, I can't call useMutation() because handleSignUp is not a react functional component.

What's the proper design pattern for this?  Should I be running the mutation in the SignUp() component?

Many thanks

```
// ----- App.js:
function handleSignUp(fields) {
  console.log("App SignUp data:", fields);
  //const [signup, { data }] = useMutation(SIGN_UP);  
  // !! CANNOT USE HOOK IN A NON-RFC FUNCTION
}

function App() {
...
        <Route path="/SignUp">
          <SignUp onSignUp={handleSignUp} />
        </Route>
...


// ----- SignUp.js:
function SignUp(props) {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    organization: "",
  });
...
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onSignUp(fields);
  }
 return (
...
    <div id="sign-up-page">
      <h1>Sign Up</h1>
      <form
        className="sign-up-form"
        noValidate
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the first rule of hooks - [only call hooks at the top level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

Change `SignUp` to an arrow function component, then inside `Signup` use the `useMutation` hook and then below define your `handleSignUp` function -

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const [signup, { data }] = useMutation(SIGN_UP);
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    organization: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    signup(fields);
    // or possibly something like this to pass your fields as variables properly
    // signup({ variables: { ...fields } });
  }
  
  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

If you need to hoist this up to `App` for some reason not made clear in your question, you can also do that.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be to go with larz solution, and it make send to keep the `handSignUp` in ur `SignUp` component as its the task of SignUp component to handle singup operation. But still if you have to keep the `handleSignUp` outside component, you need to use the apollo client as standalone without hooks.

```js
apolloClient
     .mutate({
        mutation: MUTATION
     })
  .then (res => {})
  .catch(err => {})
```